# equal height on change menu vertical jquery

Tags: jquery

In a page with three columns, I've used equalheight script for equalize the height of columns, but each time I open a vertical accordion menu the script doesn't refresh the heights of all columns.
Here is the code of script:

```
function equalHeight (blocks) {
var currentTallest = 0,
     currentRowStart = 0,
     rowDivs = new Array(),
     $el,
     topPosition = 0;

 $(blocks).each(function() {

   $el = $(this);
   topPostion = $el.position().top;

   if (currentRowStart != topPostion) {

     for (currentDiv = 0 ; currentDiv < rowDivs.length ; currentDiv++) {
       rowDivs[currentDiv].height(currentTallest);
     }

     rowDivs.length = 0;
     currentRowStart = topPostion;
     currentTallest = $el.height();
     rowDivs.push($el);

   } else {


     rowDivs.push($el);
     currentTallest = (currentTallest < $el.height()) ? ($el.height()) : (currentTallest);

  }

   for (currentDiv = 0 ; currentDiv < rowDivs.length ; currentDiv++) {
     rowDivs[currentDiv].height(currentTallest);
   }

 });
```

the sample page

```
http://www.esteticasilvia.it/responsive/index.shtml
```

Thanks for suggestions

Comment: can you use a complete different solution for the equal height columns, that works with dynamic height? [I'll try to write one, pure CSS]

Comment: I've tried to use css but in my case the collapsible menu which is located in one of the columns when it is open doesn't push down the column

Comment: What about the answer I've provided? If its not good for you.. Comment with the reason why.

Comment: I tried to use for the container of columns display: table and for columns display: table-cell, but it doesn't work.

Comment: what do you mean? my fiddle works in your browser? you may have other problems.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a script to achieve the same column height, you can use a pure CSS layout.

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/dJTVH/1/) *Tested On:* IE10, IE9, IE8, FF, Chrome, Safari

Notice: the script in the fiddle is only for the purpose of adding dynamic content, to prove that the layout is working as excepted.

**HTML:** (very simple)

```
<div id="Container">
    <div class="Column">Column 1</div>
    <div class="Column">Column 2</div>
    <div class="Column">Column 3</div>
</div>
```

**CSS** (also very simple)

```
#Container
{
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.Column
{
    display: table-cell;
    width: 33%;
    background-color: azure;
    outline: 1px solid black;
}
```